# Laravel vagrant up errors

Tags: laravel, cygwin, installation, vagrant

I am trying to setup Laravel homestead on a windows machine according to the documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead#installation-and-setup.

However when I get to the '**Launch The Vagrant Box**' step I get the following error when I try to 'vagrant up' from cmd:

```
D:/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:4:in `configure': undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
    from D:/Homestead/Vagrantfile:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in `new'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:673:in `unload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

If I use Cygwin to 'Vagrant up' instead I get this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found
```

Should I be using Cygwin or cmd?

How can I fix these errors? I ran'Vagrant box' successfully in cmd (pointing to a local .box file as I am behind a proxy), should I have run it in Cygwin instead?

Edit:

Okay, so If i replace '~' with 'C:/Users/[username]/' that brings running it in cmd inline with running it in Cygwin, so the now both give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had used

```
vagrant box add laravel [location]
```

rather than

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead [location]
```